# creating a ramdisk on second installed ssd disk on computer running Linux Kubuntu not as fast as ramdisk on primary ssd boot disk

Tags: ssd

My new Linux computer was configured with two 2TB ssd drives. It was preloaded with Ubuntu. I loaded Kubuntu on the second ssd drive to try out Kubuntu which is recommended by the primary software developer of PixInsight. I have a 32 core 512Gb Ram Lenovo desktop. I set up 250Gb Ram on the ssd primary boot disk. I also set up 250Gb Ram on the second ssd.  In running benchmark tests the primary ssd returns a speed of 2.9Gb/sec. The second ssd returns a speed of 1.6Gb/sec. I have tried everything that I have found on the internet to get the second ssd speed to duplicate the speed of the primary ssd in order to test out the PixInsight program which makes use of the ramdisk.  Being new to Linux I am now wondering if that is impossible since the second ssd is not the primary boot disk?  Impossible or Possible?
thanks so much,
Bob

Comment: Is primary disk NVMe and second SATA?  Post this in question above: `udisksctl status` Should show details on drives.

Comment: Check the specs on the disk slots used as well as the ssds themselves: one may be pcie4 and the other pcie3.  That would explain the speed difference you see.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  Both disks are identical NVMe disks.  I also tested the disks using the disk tool and they have identical access read/write times using the Disk Benchmark tool.  So no difference in the disks themselves.

Comment: Both disks are identical 2 TB SSD M.2 2280 PCIe Gen4 TLC Opal.

Comment: I spoke with a Linux project manager and he confirmed that the slowdown was a result of path that the ramdisk was having to take on the second disk to accesses the ram located on the primary disk. So I am giving up on Kubuntu on the 2nd ssd.  He suggested using the 2nd ssd  for the swaps as that would speed up PixInsight even more than using the primary ssd.  Now need to figure out how to set that up.